AWS CloudWatch - Logs Insights - Search query
I wanted to visualise three type of errors that I am interested on. I created three fields to group those errors but now I can't see how I get to visualise them on a graph. I tried...
filter @logStream and @message ~= /errorType/
| fields @message ~= /errorType1/ as errorType1, @message ~= /errorType2/ as errorType2, @message ~= /errorType3/ as errorType3
| stats count(*) by bin(1m)

Then I click on the Visualization tab but I don't get a char with the three fields.
I tried many options but it was giving me syntax errors.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I got it now, the stats line needs to be as...
| stats count(*) by errorType1, errorType2, errorType3

